# NSVisualEffectsView only showing opaque screen

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

I know there are questions that have been answered about this already, but none of those things work. Whenever I drag and drop a visual effects view into the view controller, I set it to behind window, the material to dark, and the state to active. Yet when I run the application, it is always opaque and grey, the default background. Is there more that I have to do for the effect to appear?

Comment: I created a new macOS Cocoa Application using storyboards, and dropped an `NSVisualEffectView`. I compiled and ran using the default settings and the settings you listed. Both worked fine. Sorry if this is obvious, but are you sure the `NSVisualEffectView` is actually in the view hierarchy and wasn't accidentally placed over the View? http://imgur.com/a/956v9

Comment: Yes it was in the view hierarchy. I just made a new class for the NSWindowController, and followed this [link](http://stylekit.org/blog/2016/01/23/Chromeless-window/#setting-up-translucency). After putting it in windowDidLoad, it now works.